# Can I delete /var/cache/apt/archives?

Tags: 20.04

Can you delete /var/cache/apt/archives?  This folder is >10 GB...  What do you have to keep?  Can I delete files that over 3 months old or??

Is this just temp files?  looks like there are older firmware files?

I am in a multiboot laptop so 10gb is really a lot of hd space for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can. However, you prefer to do this using the command

```
sudo apt clean
```

This is the most secure way of cleaning this system folder out.

Comment: WOW - That was easy.  In fact - it worked so quickly and without any confirmation - I spent more time confirming that it deleted the files.  It did!

Comment: It works for debian also.